# Supporting different versions of boost in .h/.cpp files

Tags: c++, boost

I have a header and .cpp file (call it Foo.h/.cpp) that is structured like this (leaving out several irrelevant details for simplicity):

**Foo.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

const std::string & ToHeader(const int msgID);
int ToMsgID(const std::string & msgHdr);

typedef boost::bimap<int, std::string> MsgIDBimap;
MsgIDBimap & GetMessageIDToStringMap();
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

static MsgIDBimap msgIDBimap = boost::assign::list_of<MsgIDBimap::relation>
    ((int)ROM_MSG, "")
    ... // a whole bunch of other entries
; // end static bimap initialization

const std::string & ToHeader(const int msgID)
{
    MsgIDBimap::left_iterator foundIT = msgIDBimap.left.find(msgID);
    if(foundIT != msgIDBimap.left.end()) // found
    {
        return foundIT->second;
    }

    throw std::string("MSG_ID_NOT_FOUND");
}

int ToMsgID(const std::string & msgHdr)
{
    int msgID = (int)MSG_UNKNOWN; // unknown message header
    MsgIDBimap::right_iterator foundIT = msgIDBimap.right.find(msgHdr);
    if(foundIT != msgIDBimap.right.end()) // found
    {
        msgID = foundIT->second;
    }
    return msgID;
}

MsgIDBimap & GetMessageIdToStringMap()
{
    return msgIDBimap;
}
```

The problem is that now I need to support an earlier version of boost that does not support bimap (sucks, I know ... but I have no choice). So far, this is my solution:

**Foo.h**

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#define BOOST_VER_MAJOR (BOOST_VERSION/100000)        // ex.: 1   in  1_37_0
#define BOOST_VER_MINOR ((BOOST_VERSION/100) % 1000)  // ex.: 37  in  1_37_0
#define BOOST_VER_PATCH (BOOST_VERSION % 100)         // ex.: 0   in  1_37_0

/*************************************************************************************************/
#if ((BOOST_VER_MAJOR >= 1) && (BOOST_VER_MINOR >= 35)) // boost greater than or equal to 1.35 (bimap available)
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#endif
/*************************************************************************************************/

const std::string & ToHeader(const int msgID);
int ToMsgID(const std::string & msgHdr);

/*************************************************************************************************/
#if ((BOOST_VER_MAJOR >= 1) && (BOOST_VER_MINOR >= 35)) // boost greater than or equal to 1.35 (bimap available)
typedef boost::bimap<int, std::string> MsgIDBimap;
MsgIDBimap & GetMessageIdToStringMap();
#endif
/*************************************************************************************************/
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

#if ((BOOST_VER_MAJOR >= 1) && (BOOST_VER_MINOR >= 35)) // boost greater than or equal to 1.35 (bimap available)

static MsgIDBimap msgIDBimap = boost::assign::list_of<MsgIDBimap::relation>
    ((int)ROM_MSG,            "") // <ROM message> (no header)

; // end static msgIDBimap initialization

const std::string & ToHeader(const int msgID)
{
    MsgIDBimap::left_iterator foundIT = msgIDBimap.left.find(msgID);
    if(foundIT != msgIDBimap.left.end()) // found
    {
        return foundIT->second;
    }

    throw std::string("MSG_ID_NOT_FOUND");
}

int ToMsgID(const std::string & msgHdr)
{
    int msgID = (int)MSG_UNKNOWN; // unknown message header
    MsgIDBimap::right_iterator foundIT = msgIDBimap.right.find(msgHdr);
    if(foundIT != msgIDBimap.right.end()) // found
    {
        msgID = foundIT->second;
    }
    return msgID;
}

MsgIDBimap & GetMessageIdToStringMap()
{
    return msgIDBimap;
}

/*************************************************************************************************/
#else // boost less than 1.35, bimap not available

typedef std::map<int, std::string> MsgIDToStringMap;
static MsgIDToStringMap msgIDToStringMap = boost::assign::map_list_of<int, std::string>
    ((int)ROM_MSG,            "") // <ROM message> (no header)
; // end static msgIDToStringMap initialization

const std::string & ToHeader(const int msgID)
{
    const MsgIDToStringMap::const_iterator foundIT = msgIDToStringMap.find(msgID);
    if(foundIT != msgIDToStringMap.end()) // found
    {
        return foundIT->second;
    }

    throw std::string("MSG_ID_NOT_FOUND");
}

#define FLIP_ARGS(x,y) (y,x)
typedef std::map<std::string, int> StringToMsgIDMap;
static StringToMsgIDMap stringToMsgIDMap = boost::assign::map_list_of<std::string, int>
    FLIP_ARGS((int)ROM_MSG,            "") // <ROM message> (no header)

; // end static stringToMsgIDMap initialization

int ToMsgID(const std::string & msgHdr)
{
    int msgID = (int)MSG_UNKNOWN; // unknown message header
    const StringToMsgIDMap::const_iterator foundIT = stringToMsgIDMap.find(msgHdr);
    if(foundIT != stringToMsgIDMap.end()) // found
    {
        msgID = foundIT->second;
    }
    return msgID;
}
#endif
```

While this works, the problem is that the GetMessageIDToStringMap() function declaration/definition only exists in the later boost version scenario (the two scenarios are not 100% congruent to each other). I know that the GetMessageIDToStringMap() function itself will not ever be needed for the earlier boost version scenario.

Ideally, I would like to leave the static bimap inside the .cpp file and move the GetMessageIDToStringMap() to another file somewhere so that Foo.h/.cpp are 100% congruent for each #ifdef block. The issue is that the bimap is a static variable inside a .cpp file and no other file can access it. Even if I make the bimap a global variable instead of a static variable, I now have to expose a global variable in the header file which again would only exist in the later versions of boost.

Is there a way to resolve this so that the two versions of the file (boost >= 1.35 vs. earlier boost) are always 100% congruent to each other and yet the GetMessageIDToStringMap() function is available in another file?

Comment: A global variable doesn't have to be exposed in header file. you can use `extern` in the cpp file instead. I would prefer to use singleton classes instead of globals or statics.

Comment: You mean add the extern keyword to the bimap defined in the .cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the comment in the question:

in foo.cpp:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> MsgIDToStringMap;
//you can remove the static
MsgIDToStringMap msgIDToStringMap = ...
```

Now in the other.cpp file:

```
extern MsgIDToStringMap msgIDToStringMap;
//and you can use the global variable.
```

But as I said in the 1st comment I would prefer a singleton class.

Comment: It seems like this would work, but what I'm worried about is how it will impact existing functionality. This class resides in a static lib that other libs reference. There are several applications we have that reuse the library that contains this class (a C# app and 2 C++ apps). So by changing the bimap to be global instead of static, will that potentially change the behavior in any way?

Comment: Adding a global or change to a global from static, will be a problem only if there is a global or static variable with the same name in the same namespace.

Comment: I just tried this out and it compiles. I'll test some more later when my dev environment is up and running. I will probably run this by the other developers on my team and see what they think. Either way, I'll go ahead and give you credit for the question. Thanks for your help!